# Are probability measures always sigma-finite measures?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

$$
\newcommand{\sX}{\mathsf{X}}
\newcommand{\cX}{\mathcal{X}}
$$
The definition of a **measure** is

> A measure on a measurable space $\sX\times\cX$ is a function
>   $$
> \mu: \cX\to [0, +\infty)
> $$
>   satisfying
>   \begin{align*}
>     \mu(\emptyset) &= 0  && \text{Null Empty Set}\\
>     \mu\left(\bigcup_i A_i\right) &= \sum_{i} \mu(A_i) && \text{Countably Additive}
> \end{align*}

The definition of a **sigma-finite measure** is

> Let $\sX \times \cX$ be a measurable space and let $\mu:\cX\to [0, +\infty)$ be a measure on it. We say $\mu$ is a sigma-finite measure if the set $\sX$ is a countable union of measurable sets with finite measure
>   $$
> \sX = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n \qquad A_n\in \cX \qquad \text{and} \qquad \mu(A_n) < \infty 
> $$

while the definition of a **probability measure** is

> A probability measure $\mu$ on the measurable space $\sX\times \cX$ is a measure $\mu:\cX\to[0, 1]$ with $\mu(X) = 1$

Basically it's a probability measure with total measure $1$.

I was wondering if all probability measures are also sigma-finite. In other words, is sigma-finiteness more general than probability measures?

Comment: Sigma-finite is definitely more general. Every probability measure is finite and also sigma-finite.

Comment: But surely not all sigma finite measures are also finite?

Comment: Indeed. Probability measures are a special class of finite measures and finite measures are a special class of sigma-finite measures. Again sigma-finite measures are a special class of measures.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I couldn't find this anywhere..

Comment: @drhab do you know if there is a diagram somewhere listing the various relationships between the many different definitions of measures?

Comment: No, but actually I just gave you one that is almost complete. You could add signed measures and eventually complex measures.

Comment: @drhab do you mind writing an answer including those and maybe $s$ measures? (just for future reference really)

Comment: I am reluctant to that because the only thing I am doing then is writing out some definitions and enlighten some differences that are quite obvious. Interested people can also find out about it on e.g. Wikipedia. You could also write an answer yourself.